# Temporarily switch to landscape layout

Tags: landscape, pdflscape

I've got two perfectly working stand-alone documents `portrait.tex` and `landscape.tex`. I would like to include `landscape.tex` somewhere in `portrait.tex`, ideally with minimal changes to `landscape.tex`. When included, the landscape document should appear on separate pages as if it were compiled on its own (with the difference that counters are now shared with the portrait document).

In my concrete situation `landscape.tex` is a two-column landscape document that has precisely one vertically-centered figure in each column.

Here is an example of how `landscape.tex` could look like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

\input{some_macros}

\begin{document}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
    \multicolcontent
  \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

The macro `\multicolcontent` is defined in `some_macros.tex` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\multicolcontent}{%
  \colcontent{1} \nextcol
  \colcontent{2} \nextcol
  \colcontent{3} \nextcol
  \colcontent{4} \nextcol
  \colcontent{5} \nextcol
  \nextcol%
}

\newcommand{\colcontent}[1]{%
  \vspace*{\fill} \somecontent{#1} \vspace*{\fill}%
}

\newcommand{\nextcol}{\switchcolumn\pagebreak}

\newcommand{\somecontent}[1]{%
  \centering
  \fbox{%
   \hspace*{0.3\linewidth} #1 \hspace*{0.3\linewidth}
  }%
}
```

I tried to use the `pdflscape` package to switch to landscape mode. However the result doesn't look as expected. Here is my naive approach to include the contents of `landscape.tex` into `portrait.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\input{some_macros}

\begin{document}
  \colcontent{still portrait}
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \multicolcontent
    \end{paracol}
  \end{landscape}
  \colcontent{portrait again}
\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want? I prefer a simple solution. In particular, I wouldn't mind getting rid of `paracol` and `pdflscape`.

Comment: Is there content that should naturally flow into/out of the single page of changed-geometry? If not, and the page is stand-alone, there shouldn't be a problem switching.

Comment: Nothing should flow in. I've got several figures (each has its own column, so can be made non-floating if desired). These figures should be displayed in two-column landscape layout. I ran into problems with `multicols` (as soon as there are multiple pages) and `paracol` behaves unexpectedly in combination with `pdflscape`. Is there maybe a more direct way to switch?

Comment: Will the two-column, landscape content always just be a set of figures that you want to align vertically centred with respect to left/right column? Perhaps 4 figures on one page, vertically centering figures 1/2 and 3/4, perhaps 6 figures on the following page, vertically centering figures 1/2, 3/4 and 5/6, perhaps only 2 on the following page, ...?

Comment: It'll be one figure per column. Just as in the example above. So `\somecontent` would be something like `\begin{minipage} \figcaption{...} \includegraphics{...} \end{minipage}`.

Comment: I edited my question taking your comments into account.